# Retain list search box when modifying list item with jslink Sharepoint 2013

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, jslink

If I don't replace header and footer elements, the list search box appears but it doesn't work (ie it doesn't run and get results). Is there a way to retain this functionality if I replace JUST the item element?

```
(function () {

var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};

overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "html";
overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "";


overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;    

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();


function CustomItem(ctx) {
// Custom html for every list item.

var ret = "html here"    ;
return ret;
}
```

Comment: You are replacing header and footer, what happens when you comment those lines?

Comment: If I remove them (by removing the header and footer templates lines), I get the search box but it is inactive.